# How use whereIn in laravel for get exactly all of array condition items

Tags: laravel, database

hi I want to use whereIn to get data from a table :

`$values = DB::table('attribute_product')->whereIn('value_id' , [1,5])->get();`

but I want to get columns that have all [1,5] items not just one of the array item

my table data :

```
{
"attribute_id": 1,
"product_id": 1,
"value_id": 1
},
{
"attribute_id": 12,
"product_id": 1,
"value_id": 2
},
{
"attribute_id": 13,
"product_id": 1,
"value_id": 3
},
{
"attribute_id": 14,
"product_id": 1,
"value_id": 4
},
{
"attribute_id": 1,
"product_id": 8,
"value_id": 1
},
{
"attribute_id": 12,
"product_id": 8,
"value_id": 5
},
{
"attribute_id": 13,
"product_id": 8,
"value_id": 10
},
{
"attribute_id": 14,
"product_id": 8,
"value_id": 11
}
```

I want just return that have both value_ids [1,5]:

```
"attribute_id": 1,
"product_id": 8,
"value_id": 1
},
{
"attribute_id": 12,
"product_id": 8,
"value_id": 5
},
```

but that code I wrote above returns:

```
{
"attribute_id": 1,
"product_id": 1,
"value_id": 1
},
"attribute_id": 1,
"product_id": 8,
"value_id": 1
},
{
"attribute_id": 12,
"product_id": 8,
"value_id": 5
},
```

Comment: can u share what your code returns from the shared data ?

Comment: I added returned date to end of my question

Comment: After `get()` you can do `groupBy('product_id')`. After that you will have a nested collection, iterate through it and only take product_ids that have two 2nd level collections.

Comment: could you show this solution with codes to me?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$values = [1, 5];
$filtered = DB::table('attribute_product')
    ->whereIn('value_id', $values)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->filter(function ($product) use ($values) {
        return $product->pluck('value_id')
            ->intersect($values)
            ->count() === count($values)
    }) 
    ->flatten();
```

PS: I don't like this solution too much since it does the calculation in memory. You should make use of [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#introduction) to do this at database level.

Comment: You replaced the loop in my answer with the `filter()` iterator

Comment: @medilies No, I provided a solution using Collection methods and also adding a suggestion to delegate the operation to the DB making use of relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [Laravel groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)

```
$values = DB::table('attribute_product')->orderBy('product_id', 'desc')->whereIn('value_id', [1, 5])->groupBy('value_id')->get();
```

Comment: but this code return error :SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'onlineshop.attribute_product.attribute_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `attribute_product` where `value_id` in (1, 5) group by `value_id` order by `product_id` desc)

Comment: you have to change strict of mysql to false in the config  database.php

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the database sample you shared:

```sql
INSERT INTO
    attribute_product(attribute_id, product_id, value_id)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1), (12, 1, 2), (13, 1, 3), (14, 1, 4), (1, 8, 1), (12, 8, 5), (13, 8, 10), (14, 8, 11);
```

Came out with this `raw query`:

```sql
SELECT
    attribute_product.*,
    SUM(value_id) as filter
FROM
    `attribute_product`
WHERE
    value_id IN(1, 5)
GROUP BY
    product_id
HAVING
    filter = 6;
```

Then built the query with the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`

```php
$filter = [1, 5];
DB::table('attribute_product')
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->select([
        'attribute_product.*',
        DB::raw("SUM(value_id) as filter"),
    ])
    ->whereIn('value_id', $filter)
    ->having('filter', '=', array_sum($filter))
    ->get();
```

This solution gets completely managed by the database engine which avoid your server the load of manipulating `Collections`.

### Opinion

I feel that this is a tricky way to reach your goal, which imply for me that your database design doesn't fit very well the **business logic/use cases**.

I think that a good database design helps doing complex data retrieve with simple queries (Using joins of course) or intuitive `Eloquent Relationships`

## OLD ANSWER

```php
$filter_value_id = [1, 5];
$values_by_product = DB::table('attribute_product')
    ->whereIn('value_id', $filter_value_id)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('product_id');

foreach ($values_by_product as $product => $value) {
    echo "product id: $product<br>";
    if ($value->count() === sizeof($filter_value_id))
        dump($value);
}
```

Comment: your code just works when the array includes two items but if it includes more or less than 2 don't return any data!

Comment: @kaveh.hd did try my latest update ?